# How to Customize VSTS Build definitions Summary

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using VSTS Build definitions. Once the build is completed then it will show the summary of that particular build. Along with that I would like to show some customized content in the summary.

Is there any way or plug-in to customize the Summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is using [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md):

```
##vso[task.uploadsummary]local file path
```

> Upload and attach summary markdown to current timeline record. This
>   summary shall be added to the build/release summary and not available
>   for download with logs.

For example:

1. Add PowerShell task

Script:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.uploadsummary]c:\testsummary.md"
```

Comment: This is working fine. I am able to customize the Build summary.

Comment: @RamakrishnaYelduti You need to click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, actually there is. You want to build an extension for VSTS and Microsoft has created a GitHub repo with a number of samples and reading material to get you started.

[VSTS Extensions Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)

[Develop Extensions for VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/)